# Deflate and gzip stream format - More details

Tags: compression, gzip, fpga, deflate

I am working on an fpga implementation of deflate or gzip decompressor. I need to understand first the format of the compressed data stream before i could do some coding.

I read documentations but I always see about the huffman coding and reading in the trees,

I want to know how the tree exist inside the data stream ie. in gzip { HEADERS, etc etc etc, COMPRESSED PAYLOAD, CRC/ISIZE FOOTER } It doesn't tell me how to or what the COMPRESSED payload looks like.

If deflate, there's a 3bit HEADER for each block, but how long is a block or how do i know if it's another block?

After this I think the documents are enough to help me do the algorithm but I can't understand what exactly I'm handling/touching.

Comment: So basically you are saying - I don't understand the documentation? What do you expect from us then?

Answer (score 0):

The "compressed payload" is documented in [RFC 1951](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1951), which describes in detail the deflate format. Read that, a few times, and then you can come back here if you have any actual, specific questions.

Comment: If it's ok may I ask for confirmation about how the gzip looks like in terms of 1 and 0's

Comment: Sorry am really confused

As far as I understood, it looks like this:

A file in only 1's and 0's.

StartOfFile 010...010 EndOfFile.

So the ID1 and ID2 that label the file as gzip format, should look like:

Start of File 0001 1111 1000 1011 ...... other parts ... End of File.

Thus the header can be read as | ID1 | ID2 | = | 0x1f | 0x8b | ? 

Multibytes headers like Mtime = SoF || LSB byte |...| MSB Byte || EoF. 

In a data block  (uncompressed) 
SoF ...  0 00(Header Bfinal,btype) || LEN LSB | LEN MSB ||
|| NLEN ... || the literals ie. 00001001 = alphabet #9 ||....EoF.

Comment: Thanks for the time and patience, I will ask once more after I understand more of the Fixed Huffman Codes and Dynamic Huffman and the rest of LZ77 decompression part